# Importance of ordered function

Tags: r

I am learning R. I would like to know why do we need "ordered=TRUE" argument while trying to change the levels of factor vectors. It changes the levels even without using ordered=TRUE argument. For example

```
x<-c(1,2,4,3,5,2)
y<-factor(x)
levels(y)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
z<-factor(y,levels=c(1,4,3,2,5))
z
[1] 1 2 4 3 5 2
Levels: 1 4 3 2 5
```

If I use ordered argument, it returns following:

```
z<-factor(y,levels=c(1,4,3,2,5),ordered=TRUE)
z
[1] 1 2 4 3 5 2
Levels: 1 < 4 < 3 < 2 < 5
```

Comment: Please read `?factor`, e.g. "Ordered factors differ from factors only in their class, but methods and the model-fitting functions treat the two classes quite differently." and the section "**Comparison operators and group generic methods**"

Comment: The `factor` function's default ordering of levels is alphabetic. But even though they are ordered for the purpose of plotting, they remain unordered for the purpose of statistical significance in regression applications (and for any use of comparison operators). Using `ordered=TRUE` for a variable changes R's statistical inferential actions applied to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You use `ordered` if you want the levels to be  ... ordered.

```
z1 <- factor(y,levels=c(1,4,3,2,5))
z2 <- factor(y,levels=c(1,4,3,2,5),ordered=TRUE)
z1[1] < z1[2]
[1] NA
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(z1[1], z1[2]) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
z2[1] < z2[2]
[1] TRUE
```

When you use `ordered` you can compare the levels. When you do not use `ordered`, you cannot directly compare the levels.

Comment: I'd add that factors are usually *non-numeric*, yet still makes sense to have them ordered, think Low/Medium/High.  Clearly Low<Medium<High but R wouldn't know about it unless you specify them in this order _and_ you tell it using `ordered=TRUE`